# Install all transitive dependencies using raco without prompting

Tags: racket

When I install a package using raco

```
raco pkg install pkg-name
```

I get a prompt asking me to confirm if I want to install the dependencies. I hit `y` and after a while I get a prompt confirming if I want to install the dependencies of the dependencies.

Is there a command line option which can disable all prompting / give only one prompt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable all promptings and install dependencies without asking:

```
raco pkg install --auto pkg-name
```

In the documentation for [`raco pkg install`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/cmdline.html#(part._raco-pkg-install)), `--auto` means:

> Looks for dependencies (when uninstalled) or updates (when version requirements are unmet) via the configured package catalogs

and

> does not ask for permission to install or update